# HHVM with custom HDF configuration requires full resource path

Tags: apache, hhvm

I am using the HHVM run as a deamon, with the the following configuration:

```
Server {
Port = 80
SourceRoot = /var/www/
}

VirtualHost {
{
Pattern = .*
RewriteRules {
  dirindex {
    pattern = ^/(.*)/$
    to = $1/index.php
    qsa = true
  }
}
}
}

Extensions {
css = text/css
gif = image/gif
html = text/html
jpe = image/jpeg
jpeg = image/jpeg
jpg = image/jpeg
png = image/png
tif = image/tiff
tiff = image/tiff
txt = text/plain
}
```

I can access /index.php but cannot for / obtain "Not found". What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You miss DefaultDocument, correct it like:

```
Server {
  Port = 80
  SourceRoot = /var/www/
  DefaultDocument = index.php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me by using:

```
Server {
  SourceRoot = /var/www/html/directory
  DefaultDocument = index.php
}
```

I dropped the Port as I was already setting it on startup with:

`hhvm --mode daemon -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9000 --config /etc/hhvm.hdf`